# Partitions are gone after installing ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 today. I selected it to overwrite my windows 7 operating system. However, after booting up Ubuntu I saw that my partitions are gone and all the space is showing up us in one partition. Why is this happening? Have I done something wrong while choosing to overwrite windows 7? I understand that while overwriting windows 7 it will format my C: drive there, but why my other partitions are gone? Is there any way that I can get my data back?

Comment: Install gparted on your ubuntu and check that if your partitions was gone or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately you wiped you pc. I hope you happen to have a recovery disk ( comes with computers original packaging ) to restore back to windows... For all your files back you need windows back... In Ubuntu you can get an assortment of you files back... Open "Ubuntu software" center and type testdisk... Install it. And then run that.., then do quick search on your computer not your flash drive ( If one is plugged in ) and then when that finishes press enter for deeper search... It will show a list of partitions... You select the one that looks appropriate an more will appear... Go over them and press P until see primary file ( recycling bin, download, along those lines ) press C on the partion, and then use the arrow key to make a P in front of it... Then continue the loading on testdisk and it will restore.. { same process or windows }!!! This is a few hour process, it takes a long time to find all partitions...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,I am using testdisk and it is showing me my ntfs drives.. though it is still scanning, but I think I will be able to retrieve my important files..

Comment: Yes, like I said the deeper search takes quite a while, but my primary file ended up being the 3rd to last partition found, so I solidly recommend you wait... But that is up to you... Any further questions?

Comment: is there any way to restore my whole partition in a single go rather than trying to restore each and every file one by one? if we can select a folder instead of a file it would be great help..

Comment: We'll restoring the partion using testdisk and making it P* makes it a boot, it automacally puts windows and 80% of data on computer, if u have windows an no Ubuntu, only windows then it auto boots 99% windows files

Comment: Thanks again.. my testdisk is still running.. will wait and see how much can I recover..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the options you chose when installing Ubuntu.  If you chose the incorrect option (basically over-write everything), then Ubuntu installer re-partitions the entire drive.  There is no recovery from that unfortunately.

You have to be very careful choosing the correct partition option otherwise you will lose all data.  And there is no coming back from that.

If you cannot see other partitions then I think the news is not good.